# Align the content of the div to the right in a flex

Tags: html, css

I tried to align the *Add to library* `div` to the right with `float: right` style but it does not seem to work. How to align that `div` to the right of the flex. Could anyone please help?

```css
.song {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px
}

.song-name {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.song-action {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="song">
  <div class="album-cover">
    <img src="https://gravatar.com/avatar/dba6bae8c566f9d4041fb9cd9ada7741?d=identicon&f=y" />

  </div>
  <div class="song-name">
    Song name
  </div>
  <div class="song-action">
    Add to library
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use ``justify-content: flex-end;``. Make sure you have not change the ``flex-direction`` to column. If you have then you should use ``align-items: flex-end``.

Comment: He just wants the one item right aligned. Not the whole menu @SachinSingh

Comment: @seesharper In that case he can also use ``align-self`` property on targeted element, or ``margin: auto`` as mentioned in the answers below. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: what do you want to align to right? text or image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use margin-left: auto on the element you want shoved to the side. Inside a flex container anything with an auto margin on any side will push it to the farthest opposite side.

```css
.song {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px
}

.song-name {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.song-action {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="song">
  <div class="album-cover">
    <img src="https://gravatar.com/avatar/dba6bae8c566f9d4041fb9cd9ada7741?d=identicon&f=y" />

  </div>
  <div class="song-name">
    Song name
  </div>
  <div class="song-action">
    Add to library
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

just add `margin-left:auto` in  your add to library `div`

```css
.song {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px
}

.song-name {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.song-action {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="song">
  <div class="album-cover">
    <img src="https://gravatar.com/avatar/dba6bae8c566f9d4041fb9cd9ada7741?d=identicon&f=y" />

  </div>
  <div class="song-name">
    Song name
  </div>
  <div class="song-action">
    Add to library
  </div>
</div>
```